# My For Loop is listing the break command as an output. How do I prevent this?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, output, break

What happens is that when I hit the enter key to break the loop, it will count me breaking the loop as an output.
Example
1. Guest Name
2. Guest Name
3.                        < (Hit the enter key to activate break command)
[This is my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iemtY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Put if block just after input command in for loop.

```
for iii in range(1, 1000):
    guests = input("....")
    if guests.lower() == "":
        break
    output = output + str(iii) + "." +guests
```